# .NET Web-service - To SOAP or not to SOAP

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, soap

I have a XSD that I have generated classed from. After filling a class with data and serialize it, I want to send it to one or more specific clients.

My plan is to use SOAP, but the only way in my head to do this would be to create "www.example.com/message/custNumber" the same soap message in different URL's and let the client continuously look for new messages.

When the message is received at the client(s), they will need to send a acknowledgment back to the server.

Is this possible with SOAP? Or should I be looking at other ways for communication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF has the possibility to dynamically set the endpoint of the service and with duplex message exchange pattern you can define that some messages require a ack back from the receiver.